# Realm: combine "or" and "and"

Tags: realm

I am looking for a way to combine a AND and OR in a Realm Query.

This is my class:

```
class Event extends RealmObject {
   String id;
   String date;
}
```

Now, I have is a list of `id`s, and I want to retrieve `Event`s with ids {1, 4, 5} and `date = "2016-01-01"`. In SQL I would have a query like: `WHERE id IN ids AND date = 'mydate'`

What I've tried so far:

```
RealmQuery<Event> query = realm.where(Event.class);

for(String id : ids) {
   query = query.or().equalTo("id", id);
}

query.equalTo("date", "2016-01-01");
```

But it won't work that way. How can I do this in Realm?

Comment: try to use loop to build a query something like `realm.where(Event.class).beginGroup().equalTo("id", 1).or().equalTo("id", 2).endGroup().equalTo("date", "2016-01-01");`

Answer (score 3):

here is the solution. Thanks to pointing me to "groups:

```
RealmQuery<Event> query = realm.where(Event.class);
int x = 0
for(String id : ids) {
   if (x != 0) {
     query.or();
   }
   query.beginGroup();
   query.equalTo("id", id);
   query.equalTo("date", "2016-01-01");
   query.endGroup();
   x++;
}
```